# Targeting a child element using the dblclick method

Tags: jquery

I am able to get this to work:

```
$( "li.drag-items" ).dblclick(function(){

    alert('Hi');

});
```

But not this:

```
$( "ul.puzzle-grid-ul > li.drag-items" ).dblclick(function(){

    alert('Hi');

});
```

Is there a way to do this? The list items can belong to multiple unordered lists, so that is why I'm trying to target the dblclick method only for the list items that are within a specific UL.

Comment: And how does your html look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wanna try this:

```
$( "li.drag-items" ).dblclick(function(){
    if ( ! $(this).closest('ul.puzzle-grid-ul').length ) {
        alert('Hi');
    }

});
```

or, to be as specific to your question as possible, you can use `parent` instead of `closest`

Comment: Thank you! That worked! I had to remove the ! though.